# Creating a language switcher for i18n app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, react-hooks, linguijs

I am learning how to implement Lingui(i18n) on apps. Everything is setup, but I wanted to know how I should create a language swticher to change between language catalogs on my app.

This is my **index.js** file

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { I18nProvider } from "@lingui/react";
import { i18n } from "@lingui/core";
import { defaultLocale, dynamicActivate } from "./i18n";

const Translation = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        dynamicActivate(defaultLocale);
    }, []);

    return (
        <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <App />
        </I18nProvider>
    );
};

render(<Translation />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

My **App.js** file

```
import "./App.css";
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <h1>
                    <Trans>HELLOO</Trans>
                </h1>
                <p>
                    <Trans>it's me.</Trans>

                </p>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and **i18n.ts** file

```
import { i18n } from '@lingui/core';

export const locales = {
  en: "English",
  es: "Spanish",
  fr: "French",
};

export const defaultLocale = "fr";

/**
* We do a dynamic import of just the catalog that we need
* @param locale any locale string
*/

export async function dynamicActivate(locale: string) {
  const { messages } = await import(`./locales/${locale}/messages`)
  i18n.load(locale, messages)
  i18n.activate(locale)
}
```

everytime I specify a es,en or fr defaultLocale the language changes, but I would like to have a language button to change this automatically on the page with select.

ex: "export const defaultLocale = "fr";" (in i18n.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `i18n.activate()` method to switch to needed locale.

i18n object API is defined in [@js-lingui/core](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/blob/8979aaf81e5f839a8406d3ac7516205113944c39/packages/core/src/i18n.ts#L141).

You also need to load the locale if it was not loaded before.

In case of your project you can use handy `dynamicActivate()` function you've already created.

Your component output will look like this:

```
<div>
    <Trans>Switch to:</Trans>
    <button
        onClick={() => dynamicActivate('en')}>
        English
    </button>
    <button
        onClick={() => dynamicActivate('fr')}>
        Français
    </button>
    <button
        onClick={() => dynamicActivate('es')}>
        Espanol
    </button>
</div>
```

It will render 3 buttons `[English] [Français] [Espanol]` each one will load and activate needed locale.

It is a best practice to keep the button captions in their own languages, so users can find a language they understand.

As an addition to the above it probably makes sense to highlight currently-selected language and disable the button.

I'm using `useLingui()` to get `i18n.locale` which indicates current language and set `disabled` flag on one of the buttons bellow.

Here is the full code of `LanguageSelector.js` component for you, you can use it in `App.js` as `<LanguageSelector />`. Good luck with your project/learnings.

```
import React from "react"
import { useLingui } from "@lingui/react"
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro";
import { dynamicActivate } from "./i18n";

const LanguageSelector = () => {
    const { i18n } = useLingui();

    return <div>
            <Trans>Switch to:</Trans>
            <button
                onClick={() => dynamicActivate('en')}
                disabled={i18n.locale === 'en'}>
                English
            </button>
            <button
                onClick={() => dynamicActivate('fr')}
                disabled={i18n.locale === 'fr'}>
                Français
            </button>
            <button
                onClick={() => dynamicActivate('es')}
                disabled={i18n.locale === 'es'}>
                Espanol
            </button>
    </div>
};

export default LanguageSelector
```

**UPDATED:**

Additionally you can persist selected locale to browser's [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

We should save locale each time the `dynamicActivate()` gets called:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'lang';

function dynamicActivate(locale: string) {
  // existing code here
  window.localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, locale);
}
```

Apparently the `@lingui/detect-locale` [library](https://lingui.js.org/ref/locale-detector.html) has very good coverage for detecting locale from many sources, including LocalStorage.

Here's how it can be applied here:

```
import { detect, fromUrl, fromStorage, fromNavigator } from '@lingui/detect-locale';

// existing code from i18n.ts

export const locales = {
  en: "English",
  es: "Spanish",
  fr: "French",
};

export const defaultLocale = "en";

const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'lang';

// checks that detected locale is available
const isLocaleValid = (locale: string | null) => `${locale}` in locales;

// returns locale 
export function getLocale() {
  const detectedLocale = detect(
    fromUrl("lang"), // for example http://localhost:3000/?lang=es
    fromStorage(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY),
    fromNavigator(), // from system settings
    () => defaultLocale,
  );

  return isLocaleValid(detectedLocale) ? detectedLocale : defaultLocale;
}
```

The last step is to call `getLocale()` instead of using `defaultLocale` all the time.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        // With this method we dynamically load the catalogs
        dynamicActivate(getLocale());
    }, []);
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to make it so that when one language is chosen when pressing a button it stays even though it's refreshed? 

Now it goes back to the defaultLocale = "fr" or any language chosen here.

Comment: Updated the answer above with LocalStorage-persisted locale settings